# Active Threads Over Time graph is not updated

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter 4.0, when run the example downloaded from [Active Threads Over Time Listener document page](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=ActiveThreadsOverTime#Active-Threads-Over-Time-Listener), the graph has not changed since the beginning and end,
[image]

here the thread group :

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show how Thread Group, jp@gc Stepping Thread Group and jp@gc Ultimate Thread Group are defined ? Thanks

Comment: thanks,added thread group info

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're running JMeter test in GUI mode. [**Please don't.**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean), GUI mode is supposed to be used for tests development and debugging only, it is not suitable for test executions.

The test plan you're using generates > 5 millions samples in a > 500 MB file which is very "heavy" for interactive GUI listener updating.

1. Disable (or remove) Active Threads Over Time listener
2. Run your Test in command-line non-GUI mode like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t ActiveThreadsOverTimeExample.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. When your test finishes open JMeter GUI and add Active Threads Over Time listener
4. Using "Browse" button locate `result.jtl` file
5. The graph should be displayed properly (you might have to wait a little bit)

   [image]

---

A better option would be using [Command-line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) like:

1. Perform above steps 1 and 2
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png threadsovertime.png --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type ThreadsStateOverTime  --width 1024 --height 768
   ```

   Once command finishes you will be able to see the chart in the `threadsovertime.png` file

   You can install JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: How you are very sure that OP is running in GUI mode? He might have just run it to show you the graphs? This kind of message gives creates negative impression on a new user.